# Amazon Connect CCP iframe is being denied even after whitelisting the domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am following the instructions mentioned in this [repository](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams). Even after white listing the domain name, iframe rendering is being denied due to content security policy being set to `self`.

[image]

**Domain whitelisting**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing the same issue. I am not quite sure why this happens, probably due to some web browser security updates and iframe policies. The only solution that I found is to download **Ignore X-Frame headers** extension for Chrome.